# Parse nested values in C# dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

My C# application has the below json which is deserialized to a dictionary which is assigned to `values`:

```json
{
  "armSpan": 1.8081974983215332,
  "handPosition": {
    "x": 1.23,
    "y": 1.74,
    "z": 2.05,
  }
}
```

This is the code which deserializes:

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

I want to assign data from it to various fields in my `Size` model. For `armSpan` I'm happy that the following works:

```
size.ArmSpan = decimal.Parse(values["armSpan"]);
```

I'm not sure how to get the values of x, y and z though. should it be something like

```
size.HandPosX = decimal.Parse(values["handPosition"]["x"]);
```

or

```
size.HandPosX = decimal.Parse(values["handPosition"].["x"]);
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

There are online converters to generate c# code based on your json (search for "JSON to C#"). With one of those, I made these classes based on the json you supplied (removed the extra comma in '"z": 2.05,'):

```
public partial class ClassYouDeserializeTo
{
    [JsonProperty("armSpan")]
    public double ArmSpan { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("handPosition")]
    public HandPosition HandPosition { get; set; }
}

public partial class HandPosition
{
    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public double X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public double Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("z")]
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

You can use them like this:

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassYouDeserializeTo>(response);
```

Comment: The `HandPosition` Property should be a `Dictionary<string, double>` or  `Dictionary<string, float>` or `Dictionary<string, decimal>`

Comment: If so, the json is wrong, there are no brackets indicating it is a list.

Comment: Not a List, a Dictionary. This: `"handPosition": { "x": 1.23, "y": 1.74, "z": 2.05, }` defines either an Object (if you know the names of the properties in advance, you can of course describe it with a class object), or a Dictionary (if you don't). The trailing comma (which you don't need to remove) suggests to handle this object as a Dictionary (there might be more name:values pairs). But, as mentioned, you can do otherwise.

Comment: I didnt know about dictionary in json in this way. Never used it. I thought dictionary was saved the same way as a collection/list/array.